# What do you call it when a piece of pastry subsides?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-request

What do you call it when a piece of pastry, usually leavened, subsides? Goes down after going up basically:

[image]

Comment: is that pastry, or souffle  (or something else?)

Comment: Mix it with custard, sherry and fruit, and we'd call it "trifle"   :)

Comment: If there's fruit under there, it's a slumped [slump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobbler_(food)) (cobbler).

Comment: @JamesK [This is cheesecake](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/121150/why-did-my-cheesecake-fall).

Comment: The oven temperature was too high, I think, the air that was incorporated lifted the cake mixture too quickly and almost immediately, the "dome" collapsed onto itself, which is why there are also cracks. Still, I wouldn't refuse a slice. It does look appetising.

Comment: The term we definitely **would not use** is subside or subsidence. Noise can subside, sink holes are an illustration of subsidence.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In US English, we would usually say the cake **falls** or **sinks**.  For example,

> [Cakes fall when they are cooked at a temperature which is too low, or too high.](https://www.delightedcooking.com/what-causes-cakes-to-fall.htm)

> [The most common reason why cakes sink in the middle is that they’re underbaked.](https://chelsweets.com/why-do-cakes-sink-in-the-middle/)

Comment: I think ''fall'' is US English, I live in the UK and used to bake a lot of cakes and have never heard this.

Comment: @Tom I wasn't familiar with that US/UK split, but it looks like you might be right; if you google "cake falls site:.uk" you don't get much back, but if you google "cake sinks site:.uk" you get substantially more.  If someone else can confirm this, I'll gladly update the answer.

Comment: As a Brit I would understand both of these, but would probably not choose to use them, I would generally use the term "collapsed".

Comment: I have never heard fall used for this (southern England) but sink is, in my view, the most common usage here.

Comment: Cakes rise and fall, like empires. They also collapse and for some they even deflate.

Answer (score 18):

I believe you say that the pastry **collapsed**. This is often used when describing a souffle.

Other words you might use include "sunk", "folded" and "imploded".

Comment: My mother always said a failed soufflé had sagged. The term is often used in recipes. 
"Sagging soufflés? Failed fajitas? Avoid kitchen burnout with a cooking class" (Washington Post).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That particular example is clearly reaching for alliteration rather than idiomatic phrasing, so isn't particularly good evidence.

Comment: @IMSoP -  'no soufflé will be left waiting (and sagging) in the kitchen', 'when you cut into it, it should be light and firm throughout, without obviously sagging', crossword clue: Unhappy about rising soufflé ingredient – sank in the middle! solution: SAGGED,

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In that crossword clue, the part defining SAGGED is just 'sank in the middle' (like a rope being supported at either end); the 'soufflé ingredient' part of the clue refers to the word EGG. (The whole breakdown is EGG backwards ('rising' in a vertical clue) with SAD ('unhappy') surrounding ('about') it.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the word **deflate**.

For example, from a [cooking web site](https://www.theflavorbender.com/how-to-make-perfect-choux-pastry/):

> Removing the choux pastry from the oven too early is another reason why your choux shells will be flat. If they were soggy to start with, then they will not rise properly. But even if they do rise, they will deflate when they cool down, due to too much moisture inside the shell, especially if you take them out of the oven too soon. The shells didn’t have enough time to form a stable crust, so they collapse as they cool down.

Comment: I'd use _deflate_ only with foods like a soufflé or a choux (i.e., something that was mostly air to start with).  I wouldn't say a fallen cake had deflated

Comment: "Deflate" can be used for cakes too: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cake+deflated%22

Answer (score -1):

With respect to cake, the word is “fall.”

https://www.delightedcooking.com/what-causes-cakes-to-fall.htm

Comment: The dv really annoyed me. So, I upvoted.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you.

Comment: You're being downvoted for failing to cite sources or provide examples.

Comment: @arp It took me less than 5 seconds to find a source for what is a common term. https://www.delightedcooking.com/what-causes-cakes-to-fall.htm

Comment: Great. Can you edit into your answer to help future readers?

Comment: I have added the cite because you asked. But I do not believe that citations to authority are needed for standard usage.

Comment: The solution "fall" is also included in the most upvoted answer. [An answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/319614/1694) that was posted an hour before this one. Why would users upvote an answer practically consisting of a  single word  when the top answer provided two solutions, two example sentences in two *embedded* links?

Comment: And how is this related to downvoting correct answers?

Comment: "useful" is a subset of "correct"